# How do i dump a collection into an insert statement

Tags: mongodb

I want to export a collection into an Insert statement that contain all the collection's documents.

mongo's dump functionality/export functionality will not give me the wanted result.

My motivation is to create a verbose dump file that the entire team that works on the project can easily read and execute it.

Comment: how about simply executing [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) and mongoimport?

Comment: the requirement came from legacy reasons, however if this is the only option i guess i will do that

Comment: It is surely a simple solution, generating readable output.